# How to Sum & Group By the results of a Union select query

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, sum

I have a query which Union's two separate queries with the same fields / data types. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT     BusinessUnitName, BuildingNumber, Description, Value_1, 
                  LifeRemaining, Sum_Quant
FROM         
(
SELECT     bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, SUM(cc.MonetaryValue) AS Value_1, 
                  cc.LifeRemaining, SUM(a.Quantity) AS Sum_Quant
FROM         tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit as blb INNER JOIN
                  tbBusinessUnit as bu ON blb.BusinessUnitID = bu.BusinessUnitID INNER JOIN
                  tbBuilding as b ON blb.BuildingID = b.BuildingID INNER JOIN
                  tbFloor ON b.BuildingID = tbFloor.BuildingID INNER JOIN
                  tbRoom as r ON tbFloor.FloorID = r.FloorID INNER JOIN
                  tbConditionComponent as cc INNER JOIN
                  tbAsset as a ON cc.ParentID = a.AssetUID INNER JOIN
                  tbElement as e ON cc.ElementID = e.ElementID AND a.ElementID = e.ElementID INNER JOIN
                  tbElementCategory as ec ON e.ElementCategoryID = ec.ElementCategoryID ON r.RoomID = a.LocationID
WHERE     (cc.MonetaryValue > 0)
GROUP BY bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, a.Status, cc.LifeRemaining
HAVING      (a.Status = 0)

UNION 

SELECT     bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, SUM(cc.MonetaryValue) AS Value_1, 
                  cc.LifeRemaining, SUM(a.Quantity) AS Sum_Quant
FROM         tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit as blb INNER JOIN
                  tbBusinessUnit as bu ON blb.BusinessUnitID = bu.BusinessUnitID INNER JOIN
                  tbBuilding as b ON blb.BuildingID = b.BuildingID INNER JOIN
                  tbConditionComponent as cc INNER JOIN
                  tbAsset as a ON cc.ParentID = a.AssetUID INNER JOIN
                  tbElement as e ON cc.ElementID = e.ElementID AND a.ElementID = e.ElementID INNER JOIN
                  tbElementCategory as ec  ON e.ElementCategoryID = ec.ElementCategoryID ON b.BuildingID = a.LocationID
WHERE     (cc.MonetaryValue > 0)
GROUP BY bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, a.Status, cc.LifeRemaining
HAVING      (a.Status = 0)
) AS x

ORDER BY BusinessUnitName, Description
```

The results of the individual select queries are as follows with the first two lines coming from query 1 and the second two lines coming from query 2:

TEST PROPERTY  |  1/A  |  Electrical services  |  515.82    |  0  |  3

TEST PROPERTY  |  1/A  |  Electrical services  |  125       |  1  |  2

TEST PROPERTY  |  1/A  |  Electrical services  |  381.6     |  0  |  8

TEST PROPERTY  |  1/A  |  Electrical services  |  80615.93  |  5  |  7

My question is how can I now amalgamate the results of the the two queries so that the first result from both queries perform a SUM as they both have the value 0 in column 5? This will result in 3 rows of result with rows 1 and 3 combined.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
         Derived GROUP BY your_value
```

Try like below,

```
          SELECT     BusinessUnitName, BuildingNumber, Description, 
          LifeRemaining, SUM(Value_1) as Value, SUM(Sum_Quant) as Quant
          FROM         
          (
          SELECT     bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, SUM(cc.MonetaryValue)          AS Value_1, 
              cc.LifeRemaining, SUM(a.Quantity) AS Sum_Quant
          FROM         tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit as blb INNER JOIN
              tbBusinessUnit as bu ON blb.BusinessUnitID = bu.BusinessUnitID INNER JOIN
              tbBuilding as b ON blb.BuildingID = b.BuildingID INNER JOIN
              tbFloor ON b.BuildingID = tbFloor.BuildingID INNER JOIN
              tbRoom as r ON tbFloor.FloorID = r.FloorID INNER JOIN
              tbConditionComponent as cc INNER JOIN
              tbAsset as a ON cc.ParentID = a.AssetUID INNER JOIN
              tbElement as e ON cc.ElementID = e.ElementID AND a.ElementID = e.ElementID INNER            JOIN
              tbElementCategory as ec ON e.ElementCategoryID = ec.ElementCategoryID ON r.RoomID =  a.LocationID
              WHERE     (cc.MonetaryValue > 0)
              GROUP BY bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, a.Status,            cc.LifeRemaining
              HAVING      (a.Status = 0)

             UNION 

            SELECT     bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, SUM(cc.MonetaryValue) AS Value_1, 
              cc.LifeRemaining, SUM(a.Quantity) AS Sum_Quant
           FROM         tbBuildingLinkBusinessUnit as blb INNER JOIN
              tbBusinessUnit as bu ON blb.BusinessUnitID = bu.BusinessUnitID INNER JOIN
              tbBuilding as b ON blb.BuildingID = b.BuildingID INNER JOIN
              tbConditionComponent as cc INNER JOIN
              tbAsset as a ON cc.ParentID = a.AssetUID INNER JOIN
              tbElement as e ON cc.ElementID = e.ElementID AND a.ElementID = e.ElementID INNER  JOIN
              tbElementCategory as ec  ON e.ElementCategoryID = ec.ElementCategoryID ON      b.BuildingID = a.LocationID
              WHERE     (cc.MonetaryValue > 0)
                GROUP BY bu.BusinessUnitName, b.BuildingNumber, ec.Description, a.Status,           cc.LifeRemaining
              HAVING      (a.Status = 0)
               ) Derived GROUP BY BusinessUnitName, BuildingNumber, Description, 
          LifeRemaining                   
              ORDER BY BusinessUnitName, Description
```

For reference
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd32bf58-c581-404b-a384-e62cdda7a131/union-all-and-group-by-query

hope it helps...

Comment: I get the following error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Derived.BusinessUnitName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
If i include the select fields in the derived group by I get the same result?

Comment: Include BusinessUnitName column in group by clause, It solves the issue

Comment: It doesn't sorry as I'm then required to add all of the fields to the Group By clause and that includes the Value_1 & Sum_Quant fields which are the ones I'm trying to SUM based on the life_remaining Group

Comment: I've got it sorry. I've changed line 1 to
     SELECT     BusinessUnitName, BuildingNumber, Description, 
              LifeRemaining, SUM(Value_1), SUM(Sum_Quant)
and it works now